# Indesign CS6 blank links

Tags: adobe-indesign

I cannot find a option to make a link `_blank` in Indesign CS6. If i open the pdf in a browser every link will be opened in the same window.

Is this a really bad bug or am I not able to find the option?

Is this only supported in CC?

thanks :)

```
some more text does not let me submit
some more text does not let me submit
some more text does not let me submit
some more text does not let me submit
some more text does not let me submit
some more text does not let me submit
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: The presence of rules for posting on Stack Overflow are not an implicit permit allowing them to be creatively worked around.